# Redshift COPY Command Error [Bad UTF8 hex sequence]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load data from S3 using `COPY` Command. However, I am getting an error:

`String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: f1 61 71 75 (error 4)`

I have check the `stl_load_errors` and the character was an *enye* `ñ`.

I don't want to replace this, I want to load AS IS.

I realize that there is an `ACCEPTINVCHARS` but this replaces the character itself. I don't want to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASCII and UTF8 the character `ñ` converts to the hex sequence `C3 B1`. That character may be shown as an artifact of how the error was processed.

If you submit the hex sequence `F1 61 71 75` to an online checker you should see the [error `Invalid continuation byte`](https://onlinehextools.com/convert-hex-to-utf8). This hex sequence is not allowed in well formed UTF-8 according to the [standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf).

Comment: So, I have no choice but to replace it?

Comment: Correct, use `ACCEPTINVCHARS`